# R heatmap with different color scales for different rows

Tags: r, scaling, heatmap

I am wondering what would be an easy solution to produce heatmaps() with of composed data that require **different scaling** for different rows.

So in my case the columns represent different events of the same type, and the rows are different observations of these events that can be binary or diff. continuous data.

F.ex:

```
Event: ev1 | ev2 | ev3 | ev4 | ev5 | ev6
Obs1:   1  |  0  |  1  |  1  |  0  |  0
Obs2:  5.6 | 0.2 | 4.8 | 7.1 | 0.1 | 0.8
```

Thanks in advance for hints and help

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off with a 3D plot, then? Package `rgl` should be quite apt at pulling that off. Another option is simply to rescale your data up front (so that all your rows have the same scale).

Answer (score 0):

To have a single heatmap where different rows have been scaled differently would be rather confusing, since you would **need** a legend for each shading. This would quickly clutter up the plot.

If you suggest that you don't need a legend, then simply scale your values to range between zero/one and you should get would you are after. So for `Obs2` you would have something like:

```
scaled_obs2 = (Obs2 - min(Obs2))/(Obs - min(Obs2))
```